# Lock orientation and avoid screen rotation when new activity opens

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

My app works in both portrait and landscape modes, so I have this configuration in my manifest for all activities:

```
android:screenOrientation="sensor"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

But I also want to give users an option to lock orientation in landscape mode.
I added the following line to the `onCreate` method for all activities:

```
if (lockLandscape) setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

It works, but when I'm holding my tablet vertically, the new activity first opens in portrait mode, and then in a moment rotates to landscape. The rotation back and force doesn't look very nice...
Is there a way to fix this? Maybe disable the sensor somehow?

Comment: Do it in `onConfigurationChanged()` and see if it makes any change.

Comment: When I remove this code from onCreate, the activity simply opens in portrait mode (if I'm holding the device vertically). onConfigurationChanged is not triggered.

Comment: @dop2000: You already have the code to lock the screen orientation to Landscape mode, so you're half way there. Just amend the tag to `android:screenOrientation="nosensor"`. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) for more info. Android API 18 also has a new tag called `android:screenOrientation="locked"` for developers who only target devices with API 18 (aka Android 4.3 major release 2) and later.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and now simply use the following code to lock the orientation before I show a new activity (and then unlock it once that activity is dismissed):

```
if (rotationEnabled)
{
    setRequestedOrientation(mSavedOrientation);
}
else
{
    mSavedOrientation = getRequestedOrientation();
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
}
```